# issue with python 3.4+ and pip

Tags: pip, swampy

I installed pip 3.4 recently , however i cant seem to use pip properly ( which is included with the latest python 3) it gives me this error whenever i attempt to import it :

```
"Traceback (most recent call last)
   File "<pyshell#8>", line 1, in <module> 
   import pip 
   File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pip\__ini... line 9, in <module> 
   from pip.log import logger 
   File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pip\log.p... line 8, in <module> 
   from pip import backwardcompat 
   File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pip\backw... line 27, in <module> 
   console_encoding = sys.__stdout__.encoding 
   AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'encoding"``
```

Comment: how did you install pip? Maybe some dependency didn't get installed.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using python under WIN OS, pip works as a WIN command: try to directly type "pip install .package." in your cmd shell.